# regex mixing greedy and non-greedy?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in which I'm trying to break into easily-processed data. For this example, I want the **revenue** as well as the **consensus** data.

```
$digits = '[\$]?[\d]{1,3}(?:[\.][\d]{1,2})?';
$price = '(?:' . $digits . '(?:[\-])?' . $digits . '[\s]?(?:million|billion)?)';

$str = 'revenue of $31-34 billion, versus the consensus of $29.3 billion';
preg_match_all('/(?:revenue|consensus)(?:.*)' . $price . '/U', $str, $matches[]);
print_r($matches);
```

Returns:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [0] => 'revenue of $31'
            [1] => 'consensus of $29'
        )
    )
)
```

What I was expecting:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [0] => 'revenue of $31-34 billion'
            [1] => 'consensus of $29.3 billion'
        )
    )
)
```

When I leave out the `U` modifier:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [0] => 'revenue of $31-34 billion, versus the consensus of $29.3 billion'
        )
    )
)
```

I cannot use `of` as a definite pattern in `revenue of $31-34 billion`, the data may/may not use it, therefore I used `(?:.*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/(?:revenue|consensus)(?:.*?)' . $price . '/', $str, $matches[]);
                                           ^               ^
```

You can make one particular wildcard non-greedy by adding `?`, as in `.*?`. Get rid of the global `/U` modifier and change just the above wildcard to non-greedy, leaving `$digits` and `$price` alone.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => revenue of $31-34 billion
                    [1] => consensus of $29.3 billion
                )
        )
)
```